# Flutter android app crashed when select contact, after scan barcode (after getting response from other app)

Tags: android, flutter

Problem: When I run a flutter app into my Android all functionalities working fine but one issue is there.
1. I added `flutter_barcode_scanner` package and scan the barcode, barcode scanned successfully and I printed it. but after print log shows connection lost and app crashed.

2. I added `contacts_service` for the contact scan. I faced same issue.

Please help me I facing from the last couple of days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using flutter version 1.12+hotfix.6 that's why it's crashing. The reason is the library I was using, is build in higher version. `flutter upgrade` solved my problem.